# UCanAccess - errors on getMetaData()

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am using UCanAccess to query an Access database (obviously...) and for some reason I am not able to reference `getMetaData()`, although everything else works.

As an example, this code coverts a `ResultSet` to JSON:

```
public static JSONArray convertToJSON(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println("Outputting record");

        //int columnCount = 20;
        int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

            obj.put(String.valueOf(i), resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
            jsonArray.put(obj);
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

When running this returns the following error:

```
Outputting record
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 statement is closed
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.getMetaData(UcanaccessResultSet.java:480)
    at passport.AccessQueryServlet.convertToJSON(AccessQueryServlet.java:76)

    at passport.AccessQueryServlet.doGet(AccessQueryServlet.java:44)
```

But if use the commented out `int columnCount = 20;` instead then that does work (although I can't retrieve column names without `getMetaData`!!).

Any ideas why this statement is apparently `closed` although I can still read data from it?

Comment: I was unable to recreate your issue using a simple console application, so there must be something about your particular setup that is causing the error. Please try to come up with a [mcve] specifying the environment (software stack, connection pool provider, etc.) and minimal application code to reliably reproduce the problem.